# How to make socket.io listen on localhost only

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

There is this implementation of ws server that makes it listen on localhost only.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port: 3000, host: '127.0.0.1'});
```

running netstat:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -ab

Active Connections

TCP    127.0.0.1:3000         DESKTOP-8G5DHM9:0      LISTENING [node.exe]
....
```

How can I achieve this with socket.io?

I have tried this but not working:

```
const allowedOrigins = 'http://localhost:80 http://127.0.0.1:80';
const options = { 
   origins: allowedOrigins
   };
const io = require('socket.io')(3000, options);
```

netstat output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -ab

Active Connections

TCP    0.0.0.0:3000         DESKTOP-8G5DHM9:0      LISTENING [node.exe]
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out, by using this:

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(3000, 'localhost');
```